# How to prove this assertion in $S_n$ for $n \geq 3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $n \geq 3$. Then there exists an element $f \in S_n$ such that $f \neq g^3$ for any element $g \in S_n$, where $S_n$ denotes the symmetric group on $n$ letters. How to establish whether this assertion is true or false?

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

- For any $\,n\ge 3\;$ there are elements of order $\;3\;$ in $\;S_3\;$
- The map $\;\phi_3:S_n\to S_n\;,\;\;\phi_3(\sigma):=\sigma^3\;,\;\;n\ge3\;,\;$ cannot be injective...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I've not picked the hint. I guess we require the map to be not surjective.

Comment: Well, if $\;X\;$ is a finite set, then a map $\;f:X\to X\;$ is injective iff it is surjective...

Answer (score 3):

Prove that $(123)\neq \sigma^3, \ \forall \sigma\in S_n$ where $(123)$ stands for the 3-circle $1\mapsto2, \ 2\mapsto3, \ 3\mapsto1$. To prove it use that if $(123)= \sigma^3$, then the order of $\sigma$ must be $9$ and therefore $\sigma$ must be a (product of) $9$ circle(s). Then derive a contradiction.

In general for $n\geq m, \ (123\cdots m)\neq\sigma^m, \ \forall \sigma\in S_n$.

Comment: Lol, so right! Here's to hoping you join the 10k club soon.

Comment: Welcome to the 10k club :)

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get it.